# How to distribute files to another server

Tags: storage, files

Let's say I have 2 servers:

1. web server (apache, php, mysql)
2. storage server (lighttpd) - I wanna store a lot of images

How can I upload images to storage server via a web interface stored on web server (in real-time) ? I've read about NFS but I'm not sure if this is the best option. Any ideas ?

thanks!

Comment: do you mean automating a upload or a user manually uploading?

Comment: user manually uploading

Comment: i personally like this https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/ if you want a separate server for storage you might use port 80: `http` and use PHP's `CURL` to make that connection

Comment: This question is off-topic under current topicality rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply trying to use a web-based tool to copy images to your server, you can run `wget` or `curl` from your apache/php/mysql server against the `lighttpd` server where the images live.

On the other hand, if you're trying to do something more production-y, you might need to clarify your question. Do you have a fat pipe between web/app server and storage server, and so want to cache from the front end? Do you have a post-production system pushing to the storage server, and want to publish new content out to a production site? Do you have too much image data to stage on your web/app front end, and need to do some tricky caching?

Comment: This is good, HTTP proxy is one of the best performing methods. Over internet HTTPS is just OK with self-signed certificate as well very secure with passwords.

Comment: Right now the images are on the web server too and I want to move all of them to storage server. My problem is... how can I link the storage server with the web server ?! I think I'll install NFS on storage server and mount it on web server. After that it should work uploading files directly to the storage server.

Comment: after some research... I've decided to use lsyncd